# Как выбрать элемент по номеру из строки?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите решить такую задачу. Заношу в переменную тексты в кавычках.
Выглядеть это у меня так `var text = '"строка - 1""строка - 2""строка - 3"';` 
Как мне вытащить с переменной `text` определенный текст в кавычках?

Например я хочу вывести такую строчку  `"строка - 1"` или такую `"строка - 3"`

Как это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос решен, туповат я конешно. Нужно было массив использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var text = '"строка - 1""строка - 2""строка - 3"';
var re = /(".*?")/g
var strings = text.match(re);

strings.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
  alert(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться [split()](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods) для разбиение вашей строки на составляющие по разделителю `"` и далее получать нужную строку как элемент массива по формуле `номер строки * 2 - 1`:

```js
var text = '"строка - 1""строка - 2""строка - 3"';
console.log('Массив полученный делением по двойным кавычкам:')
console.log(text.split('"'));
var inx = 2;
console.log('Строка номер ' + inx + ':')
console.log(text.split('"')[inx * 2 - 1]);
```